# How to calculate mean values over varying columns?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to calculate average time for sequences `AD-VV-DD` and `AD-MM-PP`. This sequence may appear in any columns `MD_*`. To calculate average time, the columns `TIME_*` should be used:

```
df = 
MD_1   MD_2   MD_3    MD_4   MD_5  TIME_1  TIME_2  TIME_3  TIME_4  TIME_5
NaN    AD     VV      DD     NaN   NaN     3       2       1       NaN
AD     VV     DD      NaN    NaN   1       1       1       NaN     NaN
AD     MM     PP      NaN    NaN   4       3       3       NaN     NaN
TT     AD     MM      NaN    NaN   2       4       NaN     NaN     NaN
```

The result should be this one:

```
result = 
MD_1_new   MD_2_new   MD_3_new   TIME_1_new TIME_2_new  TIME_3_new
AD         VV         DD         2          1.5         1
AD         MM         PP         4          3           3
```

The `TIME_*` columns of the first row were calculated as follows: in `df` there are two sequences `AD-VV-DD`. The columns `TIME_X` are selected based on the values of `X` in `MD_X`.

This is what I tried, but how do I calculate mean values of corresponding `TIME_*`?:

```
def calculate_mean_times(df):
    # Create drop rows
    drop_rows = []
    index = 0
    for index, x in df.iterrows():
        row = x.dropna()
        if ((row[0] == 'AD') & (row[1] == 'VV') & (row[2] == 'DD')):
            drop_rows.append(index)
        index = index + 1
    return drop_rows

# Drop the rows in list
correct_rows = calculate_mean_times(df)
df = df.loc[correct_rows,:]
```

Comment: Did you try anything? What result did you get?

Comment: @VaishaliGarg Please see my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code to meet your requirements.  The primary organizing principle it to build a `tuple` for each key we need to find, and then build a dict with these keys.  For each row in the dataframe, check if there is a key present in each of the three possible locations.  Check by seeing if the key is present in the dictionary.  If present, store the aligned data values for later averaging.

**Code:**

```
# build a dict with tuple keys for the results
matches = {
    ('AD', 'VV', 'DD'): [],
    ('AD', 'MM', 'PP'): [],
}

# for each row check for key matches
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    keys = tuple(row.values[0:5])
    for j in range(3):
        try:
            # check if these three columns match one of our tuple keys
            # if it matches append the three columns of data
            matches[tuple(keys[j:j+3])].append(
                row.values[5+j:8+j].astype(int))
            break
        except KeyError:
            pass

# average the data
avg = {}
for k, v in matches.items():
    avg[k] = sum(v) / float(len(v))
print(avg)
```

**Test Data:**

```
data = [x.strip().split() for x in """
    MD_1   MD_2   MD_3    MD_4   MD_5  TIME_1  TIME_2  TIME_3  TIME_4  TIME_5
    NaN    AD     VV      DD     NaN   NaN     3       2       1       NaN
    AD     VV     DD      NaN    NaN   1       1       1       NaN     NaN
    AD     MM     PP      NaN    NaN   4       3       3       NaN     NaN
    TT     AD     MM      NaN    NaN   2       4       NaN     NaN     NaN
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:], columns=data[0])
```

**Output:**

```
{('AD', 'VV', 'DD'): array([ 2. ,  1.5,  1. ]), ('AD', 'MM', 'PP'): array([ 4.,  3.,  3.])}
```